# After entering the subview through NavigationLink, it automatically returns to the parent view

Tags: swiftui-navigationlink

I'm using SwiftUI's NavigationLink to build a view navigation. This navigation has three layers. When I enter the third-layer view, I can see that the view has been loaded, but the view automatically jumps back to the second-layer view. Xcode does not prompt any errors when running. I don't understand how this happened. I'm confused and can't think of what keywords to google.

[image]

I have attached the playground code that can reproduce this bug below. Please help me explain why this bug occurs and give me some ideas for modification. Thanks.

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

class MyItem: Identifiable, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: MyItem, rhs: MyItem) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var parentId: String?
    
    init(id: String, title: String, parentId: String?) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.parentId = parentId
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [MyItem] = []
    @Published var parentItems: [MyItem] = []
    
    init() {
        fetchItmes()
    }
    
    private static let allItems: [MyItem] = {
        var itemList: [MyItem] = []
        for index in 0..<9 {
            let listItem = MyItem(id: UUID().uuidString, title: "Title\(index)", parentId: nil)
            itemList.append(listItem)
        }
        return itemList
    }()
    
    func fetchItmes() {
        items = ViewModel.allItems
    }
    
    func fetchParentItems() {
        parentItems = Array(ViewModel.allItems.prefix(3))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(vm.items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(myItem: $vm.items[vm.items.firstIndex(of: item)!])) {
                        Text(item.title)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("All Items")
        }
        .frame(width: 375, height: 667)
        .environmentObject(vm)
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: ViewModel
    
    @Binding var myItem: MyItem
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(myItem.title)
            NavigationLink(destination: ParentItemList()) {
                Text("Parent Item")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ParentItemList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(vm.parentItems) { item in
                Text(item.title)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            vm.fetchParentItems()
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
```

Comment: Change MyItem to a struct and remove the custom conformance to Equatable. You should also get rid of that custom Binding hack. Watch “Demistify SwiftUI”

Comment: Also, NavigationView has been deprecated, unless you have a good reason to support older devices it is best to seek more current tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this issue occurs with NavigationView, but when I replaced it with NavigationStack, everything worked fine.